# Close Event Cusom Menu Item

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, menuitem

first i want to apologize for my bad english. My problem is, that i have implemented in JavaFX a new class that extends the CustomMenuItem.´

I want to get a menu that can handle anything like a CustomMenuItem, but when there is a click on it, the hide event should not be there. So i want to have the menu always in front...

At the moment the OnActionEvent (click) starts the event that i want, but the complete menu hides. I'm not really confirmed with the JavaFX, so i don't know how i can catch the close/hide event from the complete menu.

Is there a solution for it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but I think what you are looking for is calling

```
setHideOnClick(false);
```

in your `CustomMenuItem` subclass' constructor, as in the following example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NonHidingMenu extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Menu menu = new Menu("File");
        menu.getItems().addAll(new NonHidingMenuItem("New"));
        menu.getItems().addAll(new NonHidingMenuItem("Open"));

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(null, menuBar, null, null, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class NonHidingMenuItem extends CustomMenuItem {
        public NonHidingMenuItem(String text) {
            setContent(new Label(text));
            setHideOnClick(false);
            setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Selected "+text));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello James, thats not my Question. If i click at the MenuItem the Event Action starts and the complete Menu hides! I can not see the menu after the click on it, but i wanna get a solution like this: First i want to click at the MenuItem, than starts the Event and the Menu will not hide and stay in the forground. Could you please help me?

Comment: That's what that method call does. I updated the answer with an example you can run.

Comment: This Solution doesn't have that effect. If i click on a MenuItem they will hide. Is it possible that you can fix it?

Comment: When I click on them, the message prints to the console but the menu stays shown. Which JDK version are you using?

Comment: Hello i use JavaSE 1.7 -> The Lambda Function in your code also not works.

Comment: There was a bug in earlier versions ([RT-29614](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-29614)). You will need to use a more recent version of Java and JavaFX to get this functionality.

Comment: Thats not possible -> I only can use JavaSE 1.7 becouse the product i develop for is only running on this